# $http.get method in angular method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my HTML Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    Name: {{user.login}}   
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my JavaScript Code.

```
var MainController = function($scope, $http) {
    var onUserComplete = function(response) {
        $scope.user = response.data;
    };

    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/sfshameem5")
    .then(onUserComplete);

    $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
}
```

I'm expecting `{{user.login}}` to show a name, but that doesn't appear.

Comment: Where is `ng-app='app'`?

Comment: have you put a breakpoint in the "onUserComplete" function to see what "response" contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. This will work:
You should do:

```
$scope.user = response;
```

and not

```
$scope.user = response.data;
```

The code bellow is working.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        Name: {{user.login}}
    </body>
    </html>
```

And for your js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/sfshameem5",
    })
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.user = response;
             })
            .error(function(response) {
                console.log("Failed fetching data:" + response);
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using $http Get

```
$http({
   method:"get",
   url:"https://api.github.com/users/sfshameem5"
   }).success(function(resp){
      $scope.user=resp.data
   }).error(function(error){
      console.log(error)
   })
```